# How do I access the inner array in Scala if I have an Array in the following format: Array[(String, Array[String])]

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and stuck on a trivial issue. I tried innerArray._1 and innerArray(1) to access the first element in array, unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
// define an array
scala> val a = Array(("a", Array("b")))
a: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((a,Array(b)))

// get first element (might throw if array is empty), use pattern matching instead
scala> a(0)
res1: (String, Array[String]) = (a,Array(b))

// get second tuple element from the first element of an array
scala> a(0)._2
res2: Array[String] = Array(b)

// get that array first element, and so on ...
scala> a(0)._2(0)
res3: String = b
```

However, you usually use pattern matching instead of index based access. Take a look at things like `map` combined with `case (a, arr) => arr`. Or similarly:

```
// if you want first element for example:
scala> a.headOption map { case (a, arr) => arr }
res4: Option[Array[String]] = Some([Ljava.lang.String;@db9ecd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
array.map(tuples => tuples._2.map(innerArrayElement => println(innerArrayElement)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`_1`, `_2` and so on until `_22` works just for `tuples` and not for `arrays`

lets say you have `innerArray` as

```
val innerArray = Array(("first", Array("str1", "str2")))
//innerArray: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((first,[Ljava.lang.String;@7c9bdee9))
```

Then you can access the first elements of tuples in the array as

```
innerArray.map(x => x._1)
//res0: Array[String] = Array(first)
```

and the second elements as

```
innerArray.map(_._2)
//res1: Array[Array[String]] = Array([Ljava.lang.String;@7c9bdee9)
```

Elements of arrays can be get by using `(0)` *to get the first element*, `(1)` *to get the second element* and so on. so doing the following should give you the *first element* of *first tuple2* in `innerArray`

```
innerArray(0)._1
//res0: String = first
```

And doing the following should give you the *first elemement of array* in the *second elemen*t of the *first Tuple2* in `innerArray`

```
innerArray(0)._2(0)
//res0: String = str1
```